# Compare collection with objects and copy the differences

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a Collection:

```
Collection<DateOfValues> collectionDateOfValues;
...
```

I get a DateOfValues Instance - lets say dateOfValuesNew and want to iterate over the collection and overwrite only values that are different.

```
public class DateOfValues
{
   {
      this.Values = new Collection<SomeValue>();
   }

   public int id { get; set;}    
   public DateTime Start { get; set; }    
   public Collection<SomeValue> Values;
}

public class SomeValue
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public DateOfValues Date { get; set; }
   public string Status { get; set; }
   publi decimal StatusNumber { get; set; }
}
```

What I have done:

```
if (dateOfValuesNew != null)
{
   foreach (var dateOfValues in collectionDateOfValues)
   {
      if (dateOfValues.Id == dateOfValuesNew.Id)
      {
         // Here Im sure to find the dateOfValues Instance I will work with.
      }
   }
}
```

But If I want to compare `dateOfValues` with `dateOfValuesNew` with `foreach` it is ugly and unreadable.

Is there any better way to do it?

The `Start` of DateOfValues can be changed. It is the easiest part - cause I can simply overwrite it.

The hard part is to compare `SomeValue Collection`. Every SomeValue can have changed `Date` and `Status` - this can be solved with overwriting too.

But SomeValue Collection can become new SomeValue or it can be deleted.

For example dateOfValues has 3 SomeValue in SomeValue Collection and dateOfValuesNew will have 4 or 2.

Comment: Why not use `Except` ??

Comment: @CoderofCode `Except` with Collection of Objects? Show me the example with my code.  For the situation that `dateOfValuesNew` will have the same number of `Values`, lets say 3. And `SomeValue` number 2 will have different `StatusNumber`.

Comment: This question doesn't seem very clear to me. I'm having a hard time understand how `SomeValue` fits into all of this, and what the problem is. As you say (I think), you can always just overwrite the values unconditionally; if they are different, you achieve your goal, if not, then you just overwrote with the same value, so no harm done. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain clearly what that example does, and how that is different from what you want it to do.

Comment: @PeterDuniho sure I have tried to show minimal code. Also what I have done and my thoughts about it. Sometimes it is not possible for me to make it more easier to understand.

Comment: @PeterDuniho if you see something that can be simplified or make the question more readable - you can help with edit.

Comment: I would be happy to edit and improve the question if I understood it. It's something I do often for other posts. But I don't understand the question, and have asked _you_ (the only person with 100% of the facts) to provide the missing details and clarifications needed. Please re-read the page at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so that you understand why and how your code example should be both **minimal** and **complete**.

Answer (score 1):

A bit tricky but this works:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Test
        DateOfValues dov1 = new DateOfValues { Id = 1, Start = new DateTime(2011, 12, 01) };
        dov1.AddSomeValue(1,"OK",2);
        dov1.AddSomeValue(2,"Not OK",3);
        dov1.AddSomeValue(3,"Not OK",4);
        dov1.AddSomeValue(4,"Additional dov1",5);


        DateOfValues dov2 = new DateOfValues { Id = 1, Start = new DateTime(2011, 12, 02) };
        dov2.AddSomeValue(1, "OK", 2);
        dov2.AddSomeValue(2, "Not OK", 4);
        dov2.AddSomeValue(3, "OK", 1);
        dov2.AddSomeValue(6, "Additional dov2", 15);

        foreach (Tuple<SomeValue,SomeValue> difference in dov1.GetDifference(dov2))
        {
            if (difference.Item1 != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Item1: Id:{0}; Status:{1}; Status Number:{2}",
                    difference.Item1.Id, difference.Item1.Status, difference.Item1.StatusNumber);
            }
            if (difference.Item2 != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Item2: Id:{0}; Status:{1}; Status Number:{2}",
                    difference.Item2.Id, difference.Item2.Status, difference.Item2.StatusNumber);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");
        }

    }
}

public class DateOfValues
{
    public DateOfValues()
    {
        Values = new Collection<SomeValue>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public Collection<SomeValue> Values;

    public void AddSomeValue(int id, string status, decimal statusNumber)
    {
        Values.Add(new SomeValue{Date = this,Id = id,Status = status,StatusNumber = statusNumber});
    }

    public IEnumerable<Tuple<SomeValue, SomeValue>> GetDifference(DateOfValues other)
    {
        IEnumerable<SomeValue> notMatching = Values.Where(v => !other.Values.Any(o => v.Equals(o)))
            .Union(other.Values.Where(v=> !Values.Any(o=> v.Equals(o)))).Distinct();

        return notMatching
            .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
            .Select(x => 
                new Tuple<SomeValue, SomeValue>(
                    x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Date == this), x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Date == other)));
    }

}

public class SomeValue : IEquatable<SomeValue>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateOfValues Date { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public decimal StatusNumber { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(SomeValue other)
    {
        return other.Id == Id && other.Status == Status && other.StatusNumber == StatusNumber;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Item1: Id:2; Status:Not OK; Status Number:3 
Item2: Id:2; Status:Not OK; Status Number:4
-------------------------------------------
Item1: Id:3; Status:Not OK; Status Number:4 
Item2: Id:3; Status:OK; Status Number:1
-------------------------------------------
Item1: Id:4; Status:Additional dov1; Status Number:5
------------------------------------------- 
Item2: Id:6; Status:Additional dov2; Status Number:15
-------------------------------------------
```

**Edit**

Alternative you could use an EqualityComparer:

```
public class DateOfValues
{
    public DateOfValues()
    {
        Values = new Collection<SomeValue>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public Collection<SomeValue> Values;

    public void AddSomeValue(int id, string status, decimal statusNumber)
    {
        Values.Add(new SomeValue { Date = this, Id = id, Status = status, StatusNumber = statusNumber });
    }

    public IEnumerable<Tuple<SomeValue, SomeValue>> GetDifference(DateOfValues other)
    {
        var notMatching = Values.Except(other.Values, new SomeValueComparer())
            .Union(other.Values.Except(Values,new SomeValueComparer()));

        return notMatching
            .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
            .Select(x =>
                new Tuple<SomeValue, SomeValue>(
                    x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Date == this), x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Date == other)));
    }

}

public class SomeValueComparer : IEqualityComparer<SomeValue>
{
    public bool Equals(SomeValue x, SomeValue y)
    {
        return 
            x.Id == y.Id &&
            x.Status == y.Status &&
            x.StatusNumber == y.StatusNumber;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SomeValue obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}


public class SomeValue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateOfValues Date { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public decimal StatusNumber { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",Id,Status,StatusNumber).GetHashCode();
        // or a better method to get a hashcode
    }
}
```